# How to go to account folder using session in php

Tags: php, mysql, session

The below code may / may not have many hidden errors.

**What I want:-** I have `session` which results as if a user is at `index.php` and is logged, it will redirect to its account folder.

**What I got:-** In `index.php` I got [see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6sqSB.png).

> **How account folder is prescribed:-**
>
> Suppose there are two users, having `uname` as **trial** & **demo**
>
> So the account folder for **trial** will be `http://localhost/Ebooks/new/trial` & for **demo** it will be `http://localhost/Ebooks/new/demo`
>
> Means account folders are based on their `uname`
>
> `uname` is nothing but `username`

For getting the result I tried:-

**index.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once 'class.user.php';
$user_login = new USER();

if($user_login->is_logged_in()!="")
{
    $user_login->redirect($uname);
}

if(isset($_POST['btn-login']))
{
    $uname = trim($_POST['txtuname']);
    $upass = trim($_POST['txtupass']);
    
    if($user_login->login($uname,$upass))
    {
        $user_login->redirect($uname);
    }
}
?>
```

**class.user.php**

```
public function is_logged_in()
    {
        if(isset($_SESSION['userSession']))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    
    public function redirect($uname)
{
    try{
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE userName=:username");
        $stmt->execute(array(":username"=>$uname));
    header("Location: $uname");
    } catch (Exception $e) {
       die('Error! '.$e->getMessage());
    }
}
    
    public function logout()
    {
        session_destroy();
        $_SESSION['userSession'] = false;
    }
```

But I get the result as [see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6sqSB.png).

I request to sort out my problem!

If my [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6sqSB.png) is solved **please do not consider the problem is solved**. I want basically `How to go to account folder using session in PHP`, but this may have many hidden problems.

Comment: `$uname` isn't be set anywhere in your code. Can we see the class `USER` please? As it's possible that you may have your return wrong.

Comment: Please remove the `banner effect` from the text.

Comment: @WillParky93 I have edited `index.php` the portion in question, may this will clear your doubt, If not please clear more..

Comment: @Fred-ii- which banner effect?

Comment: Thanks for editing your code. `$uname` is being set after your call that requires it.  Your first call to `$user_login->redirect($uname);` will always be `$user_login->redirect(null);` Can we see the function `is_logged_in()` in your `user` class ?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

Comment: @WillParky93 I have edited `class.user.php` portion as your requirement

Comment: Please see the answers posted on how to fix the error you have with `try` and `catch`. You have more issues with your logic however. For example, you should be throwing a `return false;` on the end of your `is_logged_in()` and then check for `if($user_login->is_logged_in())` rather than `if($user_login->is_logged_in()!="")` And you still have the issue of `$uname` being set AFTER it is required. Resulting in a null call

Comment: Can you please edit the codes and answer it.

Comment: Your question is to solve an error with `try` not your logic. I've given you my advice on how to fix it but as it's unrelated to the question I cannot post an answer. Have a go at fixing it yourself and if you come across any more issues/error then you may post a new question. For the time being please look at the answers that will solve your current issue.

Comment: @WillParky93 Can I edit this question to the new? As it is related to this! And please suggest a title for my new/edited question

Comment: No, please look at the answers already provided, try them out and they will remove your error that's related to your question. Once you've solved this error, please have a go at fixing the points that I've advised you on then come back with your own title to the problem you are having.

Comment: @WillParky93 I have posted a new question as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46156021/how-to-go-to-account-folder-using-session-in-php-part-ii . Please **note** link to the image is changed in that question.

Comment: @WillParky93 As I am not able, how to change the code with your clues, therefore I edited the question! Please Look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a catch if you are goiung to `try` something:

```
public function redirect($uname)
    {
        try{
            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE userName=:username");
            $stmt->execute(array(":username"=>$uname));
        header("Location: $uname");
        } catch (Exception $e) {
           die('Error! '.$e->getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Handle any errors however you will in the catch area.

Comment: You never set $uname to anything!!  `$user_login->redirect($uname);`

Comment: so, how to set it? `$uname` as per login sessions. Please refer the codes given above

Comment: `$uname = trim($_POST['txtuname']);` But you refer to $uname BEFORE that line!

Answer (score 1):

You need catch block as well with try. I assume you use PDO, so working solution would be following.

```
public function redirect($uname) {
   try{
      $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE userName=:username");
      $stmt->execute(array(":username"=>$uname));
   }
   catch(PDOException $error) {
      return $error->getMessage();
   }
   header("Location: $uname");
}
```